# Messages app: I can't delete individual texts from conversation as the Trash icon disappears

Tags: messages, iphone

On an iPhone, when I want to delete parts of a conversation from the Messages app, I tap and hold an individual message.

This displays `Copy | More…`. I tap `More…` and tick the relevant text messages to delete. The trash bin appears in bottom left corner and I can delete.

However, it only works the first time after the phone was switched on. If I want to do this a second time, pressing `More…` and ticking the relevant text messages to delete, the trash bin in the bottom left is missing, whereas the camera button is still displayed.

I can still delete the entire conversation (which I don't want to do), or switch the phone off and back on again - then it works just once and vanishes again.

Anyone else encountered the same problem?

iPhone 5s, iOS 8.1.3

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: No - I'm not seeing the same problem. Have you restored the phone and set it up as new to see if it's a corrupt software setting or database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm having the same problem.  IOS 8.1.3 on an iPhone 5.  But killing/restarting the message app will bring the trashcan back for "a while", then it disappears again.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in to narrow down when this is happening. Hopefully someone can edit in a conclusive answer if/when it's determined.